# Fitting an img to div, without the div expanding height-wise

Tags: html, css

I'm making a full-screen image viewer with navigation buttons, a sidebar and thumbnail strip at the bottom. I'm trying to fit the image to its container div with `object-fit: scale-down` - it's working width-wise, but it's not fitting it height-wise - it's squashing the "thumbnails" section down and/or causing the page to scroll downwards, instead of resizing the image as I expected it to. And it's showing a lot of unnecessary blank space top and bottom.

[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5xmetc8u/5/)

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image_viewer {
  flex: 1;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image_container {
  flex: 1;
}

.image_container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.controls {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.bottom {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="top">

      <div class="image_viewer">

        <div class="image_container">

          <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/800">

        </div>

        <div class="controls">

          controls go here

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="sidebar">

        sidebar goes here

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bottom">

      thumbnails go here

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In the demo I've set the `bottom` div to `height: 150px` but in practice I want this div to take the minimum height depending on its contents, to give the image the most space.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Would adding something like `max-height:85vh;` to the `.image_container img` do the trick?

Comment: It works as a workaround, but I don't want to hard-code a height, the height of the bottom div (thumbnails) will be variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is positioned fine before the image loads ... but when it does load, that’s when the layout breaks. So it’s definitely the image itself which is breaking the layout.

So ... you need to take the image **out of the flow** by styling it with `position: absolute` and its parent as `position: relative`. This guarantees that the image will not affect the layout.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image_viewer {
  flex: 1;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image_container {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.image_container img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.controls {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="image_viewer">
      <div class="image_container">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/800">
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        controls go here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      sidebar goes here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    thumbnails go here
  </div>
</div>
```

After running this snippet, use the **full page** link to test the responsiveness.

PS. It’s interesting that landscape or square images do not break your layout, it’s only portrait ones which do. I don’t understand the reasons for this, but I would love to learn if someone else can explain it.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it! Not without some more head-scratching though, it turned out a ```text-align: center``` inherited from higher up was messing things up (add it to the ```body``` section and see what happens)